# How to merge two data frames on the basis of values present in multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following two data frames.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | name1 |
| id2 | name2 |
| id3 | name3 |

| Column X1 | Column X2 | Column Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | name4 | company1 |
| name6 | name2 | company2 |
| name3 | name8 | company3 |

I want to merge the above two on the basis of names to get the final data frame like given below:

| Column A | Column B | New_Column | Column Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | name1 | name4 | company1 |
| id2 | name2 | name6 | company2 |
| id3 | name3 | name8 | company3 |

How can I do this using pandas or any other way in python?

Thanks a lot!

I tried using a for loop to loop over the data frame to look for the values of Column B individually in the two columns (Column X1 and Column X2) and adding the rows in a new data frame. However, I am looking for a more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

join each time with one column and then union all the results together:

```
out1 = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['Column B'], right_on=['Column X1'])
out2 = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['Column B'], right_on=['Column X2'])
out = pd.concat([out1, out2], ignore_index=True)

out['Column X1'].loc[out['Column B'] == out['Column X1']] = out['Column X2']
out = out.drop('Column X2', axis = 1).rename({'Column X1':'New_Column'}, axis = 1)
print(out)
```

output:

```
  Column A Column B New_Column  Column Y
0      id1    name1      name4  company1
1      id3    name3      name8  company3
2      id2    name2      name6  company2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, I want to get all the other names corresponding to the names in Column B arranged in a new column like I have shown in my post above.

Comment: @kamalikaray see updated answer , that part was easy